# Difference between Hadoop jar command and job command

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is difference between the two commands "jar" and "job".

*> Below is my understanding.

> The command "jar"could be used to run MR jobs locally.
>
> The "hadoop job" is deprecated and used to submit a job to the
>   cluster. The alternative to that is the mapred command.
>
> Also the jar command would run the MR job locally in the same node
>   where we are executing the command and not anywhere else on the
>   cluster. If we were to submit a job that would run on some non
>   deterministic node on the cluster.*

Let me know if my understanding is correct and if not what exactly is the difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They both are completely different and I don't think are comparable. Both co-exist and have separate functions and none is deprecated AFAIK.

*job* isn't used to submit a job to the cluster, rather it is used to get information on the jobs that have already been run or are running, also it is used to kill a running job or even kill a specific task.

While *jar* is simply used to execute the custom mapred jar, example:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/joe/wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /usr/joe/wordcount/input /usr/joe/wordcount/output
```

**hadoop jar**

Runs a jar file. Users can bundle their Map Reduce code in a jar file and execute it using this command.

*Usage: hadoop jar  [mainClass] args...*

**hadoop job**

Command to interact with Map Reduce Jobs.

*Usage: hadoop job [GENERIC_OPTIONS] [-submit ] | [-status ] | [-counter   ] | [-kill ] | [-events   <#-of-events>] | [-history [all] ] | [-list [all]] | [-kill-task ] | [-fail-task ] | [-set-priority  ]*

For more info, read [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#jar).